# Sql select query to assign the result P= ,F=

Tags: mysql, sql

A Table named student have name,dept,mark,result(p,f),year(1,2,3,4) columns, Now i want to select department wise whoever passed and failed counts with specified year.if none passed or failed it should display null.

Expected output:
Dept: ECE year1:p=5,f=4,year2:p=8,F=3,year3:Null year4:1,f=3.

I tried

```
select dept,sum(result="p" and year =1), sum(result="f" and year=1) As Year1.....from students group by dept
```

I don't know to assign this as P=4,F=2 in same column.

Please suggest what I should have include  in select statements.

Advance thanks.

Comment: please enter sample data and desired output

Comment: I not able to upload images..since i don't have 10 reputation